# How many developers are there?

Tags: game-industry

We game developers appear to be a pretty big community. But how big is that community exactly?

How many developers, professional as well as amateur, are working on games all around the world? Do sources to get that number even exist?

Comment: Around the same as the number of amateur/professional moviemakers, which is less than the number of amateur/professional writers, and definitely less than the number of amateur/professional musicians.  In other words, there's really no way to estimate this.

Comment: An lets not forget about the unknown number of intelligent lifeforms in the universe that might be developers... This question does not fit the format of this site, only speculation can be done until someone forms a mandatory census.

Comment: @Philip: Except there are ways to know how many amateur musician there are. There are even whole companies dedicated to market studies that create these kind of figures. If you don't know something and don't know how to find it (and I don't know either, which is why I ask), does not mean the answer does not exist. And my question was precisely: does such figure exist?

Comment: I don't see why exactly this question should be downvoted. Maybe we won't have precise results, but I doubt that Falanwe is looking for answers like "6553503 game developers worldwide". Market & demographic research is an interesting topic.

Comment: Agreed that this is interesting. It may be impossible to reply with an exact answer but there are certainly enough citable sources to be able to come up with reasonable estimates.

Comment: @Eilistraee Mainly because of that very reason you stated " we won't have precise results" ie. there is no right answer so it doesn't fit on a Q&A site. Still interesting none the less :)

Comment: Then no market analysis nor demographic question will ever fit in a Q&A site. I would be very sorry if it were the case. No physics question neither. There are very few real hard sciences. Even programming questions often have open answers. (The crux of the matter according to me is that this question could be answered using a scientific approach.) I am quite sure that estimates have already been done by companies building middleware&tools targeting video game developers. The UDK team had to decide whether building an indies offer was interesting businesswise for instance.

Comment: @AbstractChaos: there are a lot of possible right answers. For example: "Study XXX estimated the number of developpers at aroud 1.210 M. See the following link for source."   Or : "To the best of my knowledge, there is no study giving that number. Though there are indeed estimations for the iOS game developpers and the Android game developpers as seen in that link."

Comment: @Falanwe I only meant that it's a subjective question as there is more than one right answer, which is unusual for a Stack Exchange allowed question

Comment: Maybe this is better suited for Meta. It can relate to how much the GameDev community can grow

Comment: @BBz: maybe it should go meta. But then, the whole "game-industry" tag should too.

Comment: __10 MILLION__. Next question.

Answer (score 8):

Best figure i found is [here](http://www.gamedevmap.com/) I not sure how accurate it is tho but certainly looks cool.

[image]

Comment: Nice resource. Not exactly what I'm looking for, but very nice to have. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

At time of writing:  15,118.  ([Source](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users))

Comment: Reliable but totally irrevlevant

Comment: pot, kettle.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not posible to determinate how much people are developing games as a hobby or for a living, beacose not every one publishes he's creation or tells about it. I have developed like 3 games so far and only one of them is published.

Comment: Good point: knowing the number of publishing game developpers  should be easier. And this information would be valuable too.